# $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ..Undefined index: PATH_INFO

Tags: php, forms

I am using a code to be put as a header:

```
$fullurl=$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
    echo '
      <form action="'. $fullurl .'" method="POST">
      <table width="1000" border="1" cellpadding="10" id="navigationBar">
          <tr>
            <td> <a href="/PoliticalForum/Registration.php">Register</a></td>
            <td> <a href="/PoliticalForum/controlPanel.php">Control Panel</a></td>
            <td> <a href="/PoliticalForum/checkEmail.php">Donate</a> </td>
            <td align="right">name:<input name="name" type="text" /></td>
            <td>password:<input name="pass" type="text" /> <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" /> </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
           </form>
       ';
```

I include the header across page files with the require once. What I want is that the fullurl variable to obtain the full url of the page it is "required_once" on, and when I click submit, I want it to redirect to the page the header is on.. I added the url onto the action of the form..

But what I get is this:

```
Undefined index: PATH_INFO
```

I tried to use those instead:

```
explode('/', substr(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH),1));

$_ENV['PATH_INFO'];
```

But they didnt work too :(

Comment: Why not just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? Does that not work?

Comment: PATH_INFO may only be present/valid for URLs like `http://example.com/index.php/suffix`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <form action="" method="POST">
```

that's all

also, there is no point in echoing raw HTML
use this code instead of yours

```
?>
  <form action="" method="POST">
  <table width="1000" border="1" cellpadding="10" id="navigationBar">
      <tr>
        <td> <a href="/PoliticalForum/Registration.php">Register</a></td>
        <td> <a href="/PoliticalForum/controlPanel.php">Control Panel</a></td>
        <td> <a href="/PoliticalForum/checkEmail.php">Donate</a> </td>
        <td align="right">name:<input name="name" type="text" /></td>
        <td>password:<input name="pass" type="text" /> <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" /> </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
       </form>
```

Comment: But I do want page redirection..cause I want all that html to change form once the user has logged in.. So are you saying the page is redirecting to itself if I use action=""

Comment: No. you have said opposite - you just want the page a user currently on. So, you got it. Can you make up your mind at last?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I want. I just didnt know if you pass "" to action it will stay on the same page.. what if I put url variables like this ?variable1='2'&variable2='redirect' and add it to the "" .. will it stay on the page while adding those url variables?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="form-submit" value="Submit" />
```

This will cause the form to submit on itself (current page). Use a variable in your form to detect submission or 'regular page load'. E.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['form-submit'])){
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a more recent environment, with **Apache / PHP-FPM** you need to enable the following option in **php.ini** to avoid "**Undefined index: PATH_INFO**"

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
```