# $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] on localhost

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error when I use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` on my localhost:

```
Notice: Undefined index: PATH_INFO
```

I'm using WAMP. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: related: [stackoverflow.com/questions/7818038/..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818038/serverpath-info-undefined-index-path-info)

Comment: That means there's no PATH_INFO key in the SERVER array. Is your apache configured to allow path_info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your url looks like this 
`http://localhost/` then `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` is **not** set.

Comment: What's a better way to grab my path info? I need `www.mysite.com/this-dir/not-this-dir` Thanks!

Comment: @Paul you want to use [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) I believe.

Comment: Why not explode the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] by '/' or if you only care about the first piece of the url, use a substr and strpos to get the first chunk of it.

Answer (score 22):

`PATH_INFO` isn't always set. It is only set if there was trailing path info after the script.

For example if you have a file located here: `localhost/index.php`
and you access it via this URL: http://localhost:8000/index.php/foo/bar

**then** `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` will be set to a value of `"/foo/bar"`

**but** if you access the script via the URL: http://localhost:8000/index.php then `PATH_INFO` will not be set and you will see a notice like that for attempting to access an undefined index of an array.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:
[PHP Manual - $_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
.

> There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these;
> servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.

That has been said, try

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```